# Angularjs UI multiselect with initial selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I am using Angularjs UI select. I'm facing a problem.

This is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.user.SelectedCategories
$scope.Categories= [
  { value: 'Reading', name: 'Reading Books',Id : 4 },
  { value: 'Sports', name: 'Physical Activity',Id : 9 },
  { value: 'Movies', name: 'Entertainment',Id : 7 },
  { value: 'Video Games', name: 'Passion',Id : 11 }
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">
      <ui-select multiple ng-model="user.SelectedCategories" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" close-on-select="false" style="width: 350px;">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Categories...">{{$item.Value}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="category.Id as category in  Categories">{{category.Value}}
      </ui-select-choices>
</div>
```

Now how can I display selected categories as selected on page reload.Selected categories will be saved in the database and on page reload they will be available on the client side but how can I show them as selected and they also must not appear in the dropdownlist.

**Edit**
Half of my problem is solved by nicost's suggestion of assigning selected categories fetched from database to $scope.SelectedCategories but the rest of the problem is those categories also appear in the dropdown.

The default behavior of ui multiselect is that if I select one category from the dropdown it is displayed in the textbox above as selected and that category is removed from the dropdown list and when I remove any category from the selected categories that category appears in the dropdownlist.

In my case If I remove selected categories from available Categories' list(I'm doing that on the server side) on page reload then they dont appear in the dropdowm but when I remove any selected category that category does not appear in the dropdownlist.

Comment: So what's exactelly the problem, you want the selected item not to be appear in the dropdown-list? and the selected categories aren't selected anymore after page reload?

Comment: @nicost yes selected categories are not selected.How can I shown them selected?

Comment: as you say, they are stored in the database, so you can retrieve them on page load (when controller gets loaded) and assign them to the $scope.SelectedCategories.
I'm sorry, but without any concrete code how your database/webservices look like, it's hard to help...

Comment: thanks nicost for your help.Half of my problem is resolved by your help.I have edited my question to elaborate rest of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent showing selected categories in your dropdown, you have to filter the values in there. You can do this with a custom filter:

```
<ui-select-choices  repeat="category in categories | filter: $select.search |filter:customFilter track by category.Id">
```

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wx5DgnItlbyxQxtjHiKv?p=preview) for you.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot nicost thats what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help you! ;)